# Issues with mouse event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a 3d shape. Now the shape is rotating with click event. For example, if i drag the shape to left or to right, the shape is rotating. But the issue is when i try to rotate the shape in the next way:
I click on shape, try to rotate to left and i go outside the borders of the shape, after that i let the click up. Then when i go over the shape, the shape also is rotating in different dirrections. Probably it hapens because:

```js
 const stopRotate = () => {
    setStartX(null);
  };
```

actions only when i use `onMouseUp` on the shape, but if i go outside the shape with cursor, appears the issue above.
How to solve the problem?

Demo:  https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-tesla-71sg2?file=/src/App.js:374-427

Answer (score 0):

You are listening for the `mouseup` event on your cube. When you rotate it and the mouse goes past the shape, that event never triggers because you are not over the shape anymore.

What you should do instead is to listen for the `mousedown` event on the element and listen for the `mouseup` event on the window or body element. That way it will fire even if you are no longer over the cube.

Here is my implementation using the useEffect hook:

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-dewdney-jdrfu?file=/src/App.js

**Note:** This example is quite simple in its implementation as you may not want to trigger the `stopRotate` function on every `mouseUp` event. If such was the case, you could dynamically add the window event listener on `mousedown` and remove it on `mouseup`.